# primefaces inplace query

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using the p:inplace inside a dialog, when i click the dialog for the first time it displays the label (Detail) and on i clicking the label it displays the 2 inputText but if i open the dialog again it displays the 2 inputText without the label (step), how do i ensure that the label is displayed first.

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="Dialog" header="Update Patient Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" modal="true" >  
    <h:panelGrid id="Details" columns="2">
        <p:inplace id="selectableInplace" label="Detail" effectSpeed="fast" event="click">  
        <h:panelGrid id="innerDetails1" columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Name:" /> 
            <p:inputText id="someName" />

            <h:outputLabel value="Mobile:" /> 
            <p:inputText id="someMobile" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:inplace>  
</h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: I don't see things like a form or a save button. Do they appear in the dialog? Also to be sure, the problem doesn't exist if you reload the page right?

Comment: Yes if i reload the page then it works fine, the dialog is inside a form and there is no save button for the dialog

Answer (score 0):

The `p:inplace` element never got any instruction to close.
If you want the `p:inplace` element to be closed when the dialog is opened you can call the `hide()` function when the `p:dialog` closes or when it shows.

I suggest doing this upon closing the dialog. Simply add a `widgetVar` to the `p:inplace`, and call it's `hide()` function in the `onHide` of the `p:dialog`.

Working example:

```
<p:commandButton onclick="Dialog.show()" value="Show" />
<p:dialog widgetVar="Dialog" header="Update Patient Details"
    showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip" modal="true"
    onHide="inplace.hide();">
    <h:panelGrid id="Details" columns="2">
        <p:inplace id="selectableInplace" label="Detail" effectSpeed="fast"
            event="click" widgetVar="inplace">
            <h:panelGrid id="innerDetails1" columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Name:" />
                <p:inputText id="someName" />

                <h:outputLabel value="Mobile:" />
                <p:inputText id="someMobile" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:inplace>
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```